# Is this sentence grammatical, "Power measure going to watts"?

Tags: grammar

It sounds like the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/_p-WyPg1sbU?t=90)

> Power measure going to watts.

Is this sentence grammatical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like "Power's measured in Watts" to me, which is grammatical. The copula "is" has been reduced to just "'s"; the full sentence is "Power is measured in Watts".